# Twig - array_pop?

Tags: twig

I have a multi dimensional array along the lines of

```
array(2) { 
    [11]=> array(1) { 
        ["L2J"]=> array(1) { 
            ["VS7"]=> array(2) { 
                ["26 Feb 2015 12:00"]=> array(2) { 
                    ["C"]=> string(1) "9" 
                    ["D"]=> string(1) "9" 
                } 
                ["26 Feb 2015 13:00"]=> array(2) { 
                    ["C"]=> string(1) "9" 
                    ["D"]=> string(1) "6" 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Now I have done some looping and I am now at the point where I have access to the dates.

```
{% for sid, psuedos in alerts %}
    {% for psuedo, flights in psuedos %}
        {% for flight, dates in flights %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now I am converting some normal PHP code and at this point, I would do

```
$firstDate = array_pop(array_keys($dates));
```

Is there any way to do something like this in Twig?  I have searched about but cant seem to find anything.

**Update**

This is my latest effort, can't seem to get it to slice the last array element though

```
{% set firstDate = [dates|keys]|last|slice(1) %}
```

Comment: are you just wanting to retrieve that last array element?  Or are you also wanting to remove it from the array at the same time?  If the former, you could just use [last](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/last.html) If the latter, you could probably use [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html)

Comment: I think I am aiming for the latter, and looking at slice it looks like it might be able to do the job.  Thanks

Comment: I am still having a few issues with this.  I have updated my question with what I am trying.

Comment: Why not create a custom twig extension ?

Answer (score 22):

There isn't a Twig function that will do exactly what `array_pop()` does (return the last array element **and** shorten the array at the same time), but there are ways to do them separately.

Given:

```
{% set array = [1,2,3,4,5] %}
```

To get the last element, use Twig's [`last` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/last.html).

```
{{ array|last }}

{# returns '5' #}
```

You can remove only the last element with the [`slice` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html) like this: `slice(0,-1)`

```
{% set array = array|slice(0,-1) %}

{# array = [1,2,3,4] #}
```

... or the Craft [`without` filter](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/templating/filters.html#without):

```
{% set arrayLast = array|last %}

{% set array = array|without(arrayLast) %}

{# array = [1,2,3,4] #}
```

Answer (score 1):

pop last element

```
{% set array = [1,2,3] %}

{% set value = array|last %}

{{ value }}  {# return 3 #}

{% set array = array|slice(start, length - 1) %}

{% for value in array %}

{{ value }}  {# return 1,2 #}

{% endfor %}
```

pop the first element

```
{% set array = [1,2,3] %}

{% set value = array|first %}

{{ value }} {# return 1 #}

{% set array = array|slice(start + 1, length) %}

{% for value in array %}

{{ value }} {# return 2,3 #}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick check, have you tried `slice(-1)`?

Passing a negative number as the first parameter should start at the end of the array and work that many back.